# `test` vs `cmp` for one-bit registers comparison

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, x86-64, micro-optimization

In x86, when I have two registers, and I know both of them have only one bit turned on, and I want to know whether they're equal, I can use either `test` or `cmp` (`cmp a, b` will give zero when they're equal, `test a, b` will give zero when they're **not** equal).

Questions like [In x86 what's difference between "test eax,eax" and "cmp eax,0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556649/in-x86-whats-difference-between-test-eax-eax-and-cmp-eax-0) or [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg) say that when comparing to zero it is preferred to use `test` over `cmp`. Does this advice stay when comparing two registers? Or perhaps the fact that one needs zero and the other needs not-zero affects somehow?

I'm mainly interested in 64-bit registers comparison with 64 bits processor, but if there's a difference with 32 bits I would like to hear too. Mostly important are latest Alder Lake and Zen 3, but other processors can be interesting too.

Comment: `test r,r` and `cmp r,r` have identical performance on all microarchitectures I am aware of.  Don't worry about this.

Comment: @fuz So can you post that as an answer please?

Comment: I have not checked the tables for all these microarchitectures to tell for sure and I don't plan to put in the 30 minutes needed to do it, so no, I'm not going to post an answer.

Comment: The "Core" branding encompasses 10 microarchitectures starting in 2006 and the "Zen" branding is used for another 5 microarchitectures starting in 2017 (not sure why you don't care about the heavy-machinery branded AMD microarchitectures to better match the time frame of the Core branding better).  So, if you might perhaps reduce your requirements to significantly less microarchitectures...

Comment: @fuz: [x86\_64 - Assembly - loop conditions and out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31771526) shows `cmp` can't macro-fuse with `js`, `jp`, or `jo` on SnB, but `test` can.  But that's irrelevant for this case since you'd be using `je`/`jne` - both instructions can fuse with either je/jne on any CPUs that can macro-fuse them at all.  I thought my answers on the Q&As linked in the questions made that clear, or at least pointed to Agner Fog's guides where the details can be found.  (And test and cmp are the same size, unlike `cmp r,0` vs. `test r,r`)

Comment: @fuz Relaxed to last :) I am interested in others, but they're most important.

Comment: Pretty sure there's no performance difference on any x86 microarchitecture, and code-size is the same, unlike with `cmp reg, 0`.  Optimizing away the  immediate `0` is the main reason to use `test` in the Q&As you linked; differences in macro-fusion are mostly only for JCC predicates that you wouldn't normally use for `x<0`, `x == 0`, or `x>0` or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the scenario you described, both instructions perform identically on recent microarchitectures.  On Alder Lake P, both can run on ports 0, 1, 5, 6, and 11 with a reciprocal throughput of 0.2 (0.25 and slightly less ports on Alder Lake E), while on Zen 3, both run on 4 ports with a reciprocal throughput of 0.25.  The latency is 1 in both cases.

As for macro fusion, both instructions fuse with `je` and `jne`, which is the one you are interested in.

So really, in this case in particular it does not make a difference.  There may be a difference in other use cases, e.g. when immediates or other conditions are involved.

Comment: I wonder whether `TEST` should be preferred to `CMP` where equal in performance based on (potentially) better energy efficiency? I have no idea whether any of the research projects that work on energy-efficient computing have analyzed instruction sets down to that level of detail.

Comment: @njuffa I am inclined to believe that there is not a difference and if, it'll be in the picowatt range.

Comment: Definitely in the pJ range. But if energy-efficiency principles were followed in *all* situations where they can arise in the instruction picking process of a compiler, it could add up. Hypothesis: `TEST` involves fewer switching transistors than `CMP` since there are no carries to propagate.