# Which one is faster/optimized if (a==false) or if (a != true)

Tags: c, embedded

I am writing an embedded C code.
Which if condition would be faster/optimized:

```
if (a == false)
{
    Some code
}
```

OR

```
if (a != true)
{
    Some code
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that it matters (e.g. because it's the hotspot of the whole program), examine the optimized assembly outputs from the compiler. It's very likely that they are identical.

Comment: The question is senseless without a specific architecture in mind. Please edit it so that it can be answered. (Though people will still attempt to answer questions that can be answered, but that's how it is...)

Comment: Stylistically neither is good practice. Testing a Boolean for equality to a Boolean literal is unnecessary and in C where true and false are defined rather then built-in it is potentially unsafe.  `if( !a )` is better (not faster). The performance is irrelevant; it is unlikely to make any difference, and may even generate identical code. But really if you are second guessing the compiler at this level, you are not going to be very productive. You should generally consider performance at the algorithm and data structure design level, not at the code generation level; that is the compiler's job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading this question, the first thing that came to my mind is "That's ridiculous, the compiler knows better and will optimize it anyway, right?"

Well, turns out I was wrong, [here is how MSVC /O2 compiles it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r51crfMaq):

With `if (a == false)`:

```
84 C9    | test    cl, cl
```

With `if (a != true)`:

```
80 F9 01 | cmp     cl, 1
```

Well, that's weird. Mike Nakis explained the difference between `cmp` and `test` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39558974/13253010). And Peter Cordes commented below:

> There can be a perf difference on Intel Core2 or Nehalem, where TEST can macro-fuse with more flavours of JCC than CMP. e.g. Core2 and Nehalem can macro-fuse test eax,eax / js, but not cmp eax,0 / js. Nehalem can macro-fuse cmp eax,0 / jl, though. (Core2 can't, but Core2 can only macro-fuse at all in 32-bit mode).

I believe this is true, `test` can be faster on some CPUs, but I don't believe its effect is measurable in practical scenarios.

Weirdly enough, for GCC, both `-O2` and `-O3` prefer `cmp` over `test` and will produce the same [output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9n15K5b6G) for both cases.

Related: [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg, 0 vs OR reg, reg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/13253010)

Comment: Note that the question is tagged with `embedded`, so it's likely that the author is not targeting the X86 ISA. These differences in the generated code may still hold, but only the author is able to find it out.

Comment: Yes, I agree in practical scenario it might not be possible to measure the difference. But it's good to  understand the difference and write the code correct/optimized in the first place... thanks for the answer..

Comment: This is what you'd expect from a naive `bool` implementation that simply did the equivalent of `typedef uint8_t bool;`.  In that case the tests expand to `if (a == 0)` and `if (a != 1)` which are different for a general `uint8_t`, and the compiler generates the correct code for each.  gcc optimizes on the assumption that a `bool` will never contain any value except 0 and 1.  MSVC may not be performing such an optimization, either because they never bothered to implement it, or to avoid breaking code that does weird hacks like storing other values in a `bool` variable.

Comment: For gcc, the relevant difference is that `cmp cl, 1` sets the carry flag when `cl == 0`, whereas `test cl, cl` sets the zero flag.  Using the carry flag allows the compiler to do the `sbb` hack to get a 32-bit result.  For the zero flag,  it could use `setz al`, but that only writes the low 8 bits, so they'd need another instruction to do `xor eax, eax` first.

Answer (score 3):

If `a` is of type `bool`, you won't be able to spot a difference — probably even if you look at the assembly language code.  Certainly, it is unlikely to be a measurable difference, especially if `Some code` is more than a single instruction (or thereabouts).  But only measurement or scrutiny of the assembly language can show you the difference.

If `a` is of type `int` (or any other non-`bool` type), the conditions have different meanings and at most one of them is correct.  The first is equivalent to `a == 0`; the second is equivalent to `a != 1`.  Unless `a` is restricted to the range `0` and `1`, the results are different when `a` is `2`, for example.

The idiomatic test would be `if (!a)` and that works the same for `bool` and non-`bool` types.  You probably won't be able to spot any difference here, either.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing. Or just do `if (!a) { /* code */ }`