# Assembler error (operand type mismatch for `setz') after upgrading gcc 4.8 / devtoolset-2

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

After upgrading to gcc 4.8 via devtoolset-2, I can no longer compile one third party file within our legacy app, it complains of `Error: operand type mismatch for setz`
We didn't write the code and it has been compiling for 10+ years on a variety of gcc versions.

I've upgraded binutils as well.

I don't know assembler. There are only two `setz` commands in the code.  What's wrong with the syntax and how can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

```
    setz %%bl;\
    cmpb $0,%%al;\
    setz %0;\
    xorb %%bl,2(%%edi);\
```

32-bit Centos 6. Core 2 Duo. Compile Line:

```
cc -W -Wall -O3 -DHAS_STDINT -Wall -mmmx -fasm -c -o h264/decoder/biaridecod.o h264/decoder/biaridecod.c
h264/decoder/biaridecod.c: Assembler messages:
h264/decoder/biaridecod.c:319: Error: operand type mismatch for `setz'
```

Tool Info

```
$ which as cc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/as
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/cc
$ as --version
GNU assembler version 2.23.52.0.1-10.el6 20130226
$ cc --version
cc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
```

Code Fragment

```
inline unsigned int biari_decode_symbol(DecodingEnvironmentPtr dep, BiContextTypePtr bi_ct )
{
    unsigned int bit;

    asm volatile("\
    movl $0,%0;\
    movl %1,%%esi;\
    movl %2,%%edi;\
    movl 4(%%esi),%%eax;\
    movzwl (%%edi),%%ebx;\
    movl 8(%%esi),%%ecx;\
    movl %%eax,%%edx;\
    shrl $6,%%eax;\
    andl $3,%%eax;\
    movzbl rLPS_table_64x4(%%eax,%%ebx,4),%%ebx;\
    subl %%ebx,%%edx;\
    movzbl 2(%%edi),%%eax;\
    cmpl %%edx,%%ecx;\
    jge DL_BIGA;\
    movl %%eax,%0;\
    cmpw $62,(%%edi);\
    jge DL_ENDA;\
    incw (%%edi);\
    jmp DL_ENDA;\
DL_BIGA:\
    subl %%edx,%%ecx;\
    movl %%ebx,%%edx;\
    movl %%ecx,8(%%esi);\
    cmpw $0,(%%edi);\
    setz %%bl;\
    cmpb $0,%%al;\
    setz %0;\
    xorb %%bl,2(%%edi);\
    movzwl (%%edi),%%eax;\
    movzwl AC_next_state_LPS_64(,%%eax,2),%%ebx;\
    movw %%bx,(%%edi);\
DL_ENDA:\
    bsr %%edx,%%ebx;\
    movl $8,%%ecx;\
    subl %%ebx,%%ecx;\
    xorl %%eax,%%eax;\
    cmpl $0,%%ecx;\
    cmovle %%eax,%%ecx;\
    movl %%ecx,%%ebx;\
    shll %%cl,%%edx;\
    movl %%edx,4(%%esi);\
    cmpl $0,%%ebx;\
    jle DL_WHILE_END;\
DL_WHILEA:\
    cmp $0,16(%%esi);\
    jg DL_IFA;\
    movl 20(%%esi),%%eax;\
    movl 24(%%esi),%%edi;\
    movl (%%eax),%%edx;\
    incl (%%eax);\
    movzbl (%%edi,%%edx),%%ecx;\
    movl $8,16(%%esi);\
    movl %%ecx,12(%%esi);\
    DL_IFA:\
    movl 12(%%esi),%%edx;\
    movl 16(%%esi),%%ecx;\
    movl $1,%%eax;\
    cmpl %%ecx,%%ebx;\
    cmovl %%ebx,%%ecx;\
    shll %%cl,8(%%esi);\
    subl %%ecx,16(%%esi);\
    shll %%cl,%%eax;\
    subl %%ecx,%%ebx;\
    decl %%eax;\
    movl 16(%%esi),%%ecx;\
    shrl %%cl,%%edx;\
    andl %%eax,%%edx;\
    orl %%edx,8(%%esi);\
    cmpl $0,%%ebx;\
    jg DL_WHILEA;\
DL_WHILE_END:"
    :"=g"(bit)
    :"g"(dep),"g"(bi_ct)
    :"eax","ebx","ecx","edx","esi","edi","mm0","mm1","mm2","mm3","mm4","mm5","mm6","mm7");

    return(bit);
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the operands being passed to the extended inline assembly. Unfortunately you snipped that important bit off and replaced it with `... more stuff here...` I suspect that the issue is with this instruction `setz %0`, and my guess is that `%0` is not an 8 bit register or 8-bit memory operand.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I've added the full asm routine. As mentioned, I don't know assembly so any suggestions to get it to compile are greatly appreciated

Comment: What if you use `unsigned char bit` instead.

Comment: I can't say enough how fugly that is.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use `r`, but instead should use `q`.  If registers get tight, `r` will try to use `sil`, which doesn't work in 32bit.  Also, I don't think he can use either `r` or `q` since he's clobbered everything.

Comment: Given all the clobbers it will be forced to a memory operand.

Comment: My recommendation is the same as Michael's: Use `unsigned char bit`.

Comment: If you're lucky there's a plain C version of this function that's meant to be used on non-Intel x86 CPUs that you can use instead. Like say the one here: http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/doc/ldec/html/biaridecod_8c_source.html#l00168

Comment: Trying `unsigned char bit` fixes the `setz` error but instead produces three identical errors `bad register name `%bpl'`, which doesn't even appear in the code!

Comment: Progress.  Now change `=g` to `=m`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!!

Comment: `movl $0,%0;`?  Really?  If the rest of the code is [this badly optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and), you'd probably get better results with a rewrite in C.  I also see an `incl (%%eax)` right after loading `(%%eax)` into a register.  This looks like a really bad use of inline asm.  It even clobbers the MMX regs for no reason; it doesn't even touch them.

Comment: Also, you're only just now upgrading to gcc 4.8?  If you're upgrading, might as well upgrade to 6.3, or at least 5.4.  (7.x is out, but it's still pretty new.)

Comment: Peter, it is an early version of the official H.264 AVC reference decoder.  Written by a committee and a horrible horrible mess.  We've got our own code to manage so no time to fix that monster.  The target is 32-bit Centos so we've been using the standard gcc 4.4.  We'd need to build newer gcc's from source -- as soon as there's time :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes "movl $0,%0" - Actually, this part makes sense, since `%0` cannot be a register (they clobber every 32bit register that would work with `setz`).  `xor` doesn't work well with 2 memory operands which leaves `movl`.  OTOH, that begs the question: Why are they using "=g" for something that *must* be a memory location to work correctly? I struggled with the mmx thing too, but couldn't come up with a reason either.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: oh right, I skimmed the comments saying this code ran out of registers, but didn't make the connection that even `%0` wasn't a register!  Double-yuck.  I can still complain about [`cmpl $0,%%ebx;` instead of `test %%ebx,%%ebx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806), though.  Core2 macro-fuses `test/jle` but not `cmp/jle`, and they're actually running on Core2. (For the MMX: probably they just copy-pasted their clobbers from the MMX version to the scalar fallback).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: there's no `ebp` clobber.  Oh, probably newer gcc defaults to `-fomit-frame-pointer`, and `setz %%ebp` is an error.  And it's 32-bit code so you can't `setz %%bpl`.  With constraints for dummy outputs that let the compiler choose registers instead of hard-coding everything, this could be avoided (e.g. with `=q` for a register that has an accessible low-byte).

Comment: Unless profiling shows this code is an actual hot-spot, I guess it's not worth trying to do anything if it works.  It's so nasty that rewriting this loop from scratch (in C) would probably be the best option.

Comment: Yup, OP updated the compiler which changed the optimizations.  Everything sort of followed from that.  The real fix here is to junk this code and move to C (like the code Ross linked).  But since that's not a practical option here, the "minimum change needed to fix it" seems like the best solution.