# How to get SF = 1 with AND operation?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, flags

Is it possible to get sign flag equal 1 with these instructions?

```
movzx ecx, byte ptr[eax]
and ecx, 8000000Fh
jns short loc_401073
```

There is an `and` between the `ecx` register and 8000000Fh. In `ecx` can be a number in the range 00h-FFh, but I am not sure if it is possible to get SF=1. Could someone help me?

Comment: It would be sensible if it were movsx instead.  Maybe it ought to be.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change it. I am doing dissasembling.

Comment: Then whoever (or whatever compiler) created this code did a bad job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the range of `ecx` is indeed limited to `00h-FFh`, SF is never going to be set as a result of `and ecx, 8000000Fh` because the most significant bit is always clear.

Answer (score 1):

For example (if you need to load a unsigned integer from an 8 bit value in ECX's register), you can write:

```
MovZX ECX,byte ptr[EAX]
Test  CL,080H
JZ    short loc_401073
```

In this case, instead of the jump instruction, if you need to get the sign of the input, you can write:

```
SetNZ AL  ; AL's register contains 1 if sign else contains 0
```

If you want to extend the sign of input value, you can write:

```
MovSX ECX,byte ptr[EAX]
Or    ECX,ECX
JNS   short loc_401073
```

In this case, instead of the jump instruction, if you need to get the sign of the input, you can write:

```
SetS  AL  ; AL's register contains 1 if sign else contains 0
```

Comment: `Or    ECX,ECX` is worse than `test ecx,ecx`: It can't macro-fuse with `jcc` (but test/jns can fuse on AMD at least).  It also writes a register so it uses up a physical register (for register-renaming).  It also introduces an extra cycle of latency in the dep chain for anything that reads `ecx`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/224132

Comment: I have read the documentation on alternatives to CMP ECX, 0, as OR ECX, ECX and you are right: it is much better TEST ECX, ECX; by now I will use that.