# x86 assembly jl doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86, 32-bit, att

I'm coding in x86 assembly (AT&T syntax) on 64-bit Ubuntu (so I'm using `as --32` and `ld -melf_i386`, which has been working fine for other exercises so far).

The `jl` instruction is working opposite to what I expected. I can actually get the code to work properly with `jg`, which would basically solve my problem, but I'd like to find out the underlying issue here.

The code snippet is the following:

```
   # Open file for reading
   movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax         # prepare syscall 5 
   movl $input_file_name, %ebx      # move input file name into %ebx
   movl $0, %ecx                    # open in read-only mode
   movl $0666, %edx     
   int $LINUX_SYSCALL               # execute system call,
                                   # sys_open returns file descriptor in %eax

   movl %eax, ST_INPUT_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp) # store the input file descriptor away

   # This will test and see if %eax is negative. 
   # If it is not negative, it will jump to continue_processing.
   # Otherwise it will handle the error condition that the negative number represents.
   cmpl $0, %eax
   jl continue_processing

   pushl $no_open_file_msg
   pushl $no_open_file_code
   call error_exit

continue_processing:

   # Open file for writing
   movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax         # prepare syscall 5
```

...and the program continues, though the rest should be irrelevant for this issue.

Debugging with gdbgui, I see the open sys call returns the input file descriptor (eax = 3) without a problem.
Then you compare 0 to 3. If I'm not an idiot, 0 < 3 so the `jl` instruction [should take you to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Tjm.png) `continue_processing`, but [it does not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtQJ.png).

However, if I instead use `jg`, it works. The open sys call [returns 3 in eax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ7ky.png) and `jg` [properly jumps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Xnq.png) to `continue_processing`.

I've read that the order of the operands for jumps may depend on the assembler. Could that be the case here? Compiling with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib` has the same behavior. I also tried swapping the order to `cmpl %eax, $0` but I get Error: operand type mismatch for 'cmp'.

Or could it just be a quirk of the fact that this 32-bit code is being run on 64-bit Ubuntu?

I am reading the book [Programming From the Ground Up](https://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf). On page 125 the book example interjects a `.section .data` right after the `jl continue_processing`, inserts some labels and `.ascii` commands, and then resumes the code with a `.section .text` right before the `pushl $no_open_file_msg`. To clean up the code, I've consolidated the `.section .data` up on top and so do not require a second `.section .text`. It doesn't seem to affect the `jl` issue but I thought I'd mention it in case the problem does actually lie there.

Comment: The book you are reading is Programming From the Ground Up (I added a reference in your question). The code in question is on page 125. This is in fact an error in the book and it should be `JGE` and not `JL`. This error has been reported on the bug tracking system for the book. That bug report is here: https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?17654 . Unfortunately the book hasn't been updated in a decade. You can find a list of all the reported problems here: https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=pgubook

Comment: Yes, that is the book. Also, great link, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AT&T syntax, the order of operands is exchanged compared to Intel syntax.  For this reason,

```
cmpl $0, %eax
```

actually computes eax − 0 and sets flags instead of computing 0 − eax as you might expect.  Thus, all the flags are set the other way round than you expect initially, causing the issue you observe.  There is not really a way to remedy this problem as it isn't really wrong.  I recommend you to get used to this quirk.

As a general note, it's usually a good idea to use the `testl` instruction instead of comparing values with zero.  `testl %eax,%eax` is more compact than `cmp $0,%eax` in the machine code and faster on some microarchitectures, too.
`testl` sets flags according to the bitwise and of its operands, so if eax is negative, SF is set after `testl %eax,%eax` which you can check like this:

```
testl %eax,%eax
jns continue_processing
```

Comment: CF=0 after `and` **always**. But he can test SF `js negative_eax_detected`. ... and remedy is to use Intel syntax.

Comment: @Ped7g: It's more efficient to use JL instead of JS.  Test (and cmp against zero) always clear OF as well, so it's equivalent to testing SF directly, but can macro-fuse on more CPUs.  i.e.`test %eax,%eax` / `jl negative_eax_detected`.  [TEST same,same and CMP-with-zero set all flags identically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806), except AF.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, it's odd because the book is all x86 AT&T assembly and the author used jl when I suppose he meant jg. But this is good enough, I have no problem getting used to the quirk.

Comment: @JaimeSalazar Ah the book is Programming from the Ground Up page 125

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you, I confused CF and SF.

Comment: `testl` is only faster than `cmp` if you use `jge` instead of `jns`.  You can think of `test same,same` as a peephole optimization for comparing against zero, because it sets flags identically.