# Pass values from C program to Assembly language

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I would like to pass values from C program to Assembly using the linked assembly method instead of inline assembly method in C.
Below is the Assembly program(GCD) which is am working on.

```
;gcdasm.nasm
bits 64
section .text
global gcdasm
gcdasm:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rax, [rbp+4]        ;load rax with x
    mov rbx, [rbp+8]        ;load rbx with y
top:
    cmp rax, rbx            ;x(rax) has to be larger than y(rbx)
    je exit                 ;if x=y then exit and return value y
    jb xchange              ;if x<y then swap x and y
modulo:
    cqo                     ;RDX:RAX sign extend
    div rbx                 ;div rdx:rax with rbx
    cmp rdx, 0              ;check remider if its 0
    je exit                 ;if reminder is 0 then exit return return y
    mov rax, rdx            ;reminder rdx as next dividend
    jmp modulo              ;loop 
xchange:
    xchg rax, rbx           ;swap x and y
    jmp modulo

exit:
    mov rax, rbx            ;Return c program with the divisor y
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

And this is the C program from with I am trying to pass the values to assembly program

```
//gcd.c
#include<stdio.h>

extern int gcdasm(int x, int y); 

int main(void){
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int result=0;

    x = 46; 
    y = 90; 
    printf("%d and %d have a gcd of %d\n", x,y,gcdasm(x,y));

    x = 55;
    y = 66;
    printf("%d and %d have a gcd of %d\n", x,y,gcdasm(x,y));

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile using the below method and run it. I get either error `Floating point exception` or an empty prompt waiting for input

```
$ nasm -felf64 gcdasm.nasm -o gcdasm.o
$ gcc gcdasm.o gcd.c -o gcd
$ ./gcd 
Floating point exception
$ ./gcd
```

I am unable to figure out the error. Kindly help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: 64-bit calling convention passes the first 6 integer class parameters in registers (not on the stack).There is a summary of the 64-bit calling convention here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI . You can find the complete 64-bit ABI here: https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much and also for the links.
    mov rax, rdi        ;load rax with x
    mov rbx, rsi        ;load rbx with y

Comment: @MichaelPetch, my fault. The instruction is correct. Didn't have enough coffee yet...

Comment: Apologies for saying `mov rsp, rbp` should be deleted. It is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Passing arguments to `gcdasm()`

The two `int` arguments are passed through registers, not the stack. The first and second arguments are passed in the lower-half of `rdi` and `rsi` (i.e.: `edi` and `esi`), respectively. So, by sign extending `edi` and `esi` into `rax` and `rbx` respectively, you load the passed arguments into those registers:

```
movsx rax, edi  ;load rax with x
movsx rbx, esi  ;load rbx with y
```

However, note that `rbx` is not a *scratch register*, therefore the *callee* needs to save it before modifying it and then restore it back before leaving the `gcdasm` function.

You can simply replace `rbx` by `rcx` (which isn't a *callee-saved* register) everywhere in your code. You don't need `rbp` at all, so you can remove all the instructions where `rbp` appears.

---

#### Other problems

- There is also a problem with the logic of the program with:

  ```
  mov rax, rdx   ;reminder rdx as next dividend
  ```

  Instead of this, the *divisor* (`rcx`) should become the *dividend* (`rax`) and the *remainder* (`rdx`) should become the *divisor* (`rcx`), that is:

  ```
  mov rax, rcx
  mov rcx, rdx
  ```
- When dividing **signed** values, you have to use the `idiv` instruction, not `div`.

---

#### Improvement

There are also some reasons regarding performance and code size to use `test rdx, rdx` instead of `cmp rdx, 0` for [comparing `rdx` against zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/8012646).

---

With all that above in mind:

```
;gcdasm.nasm
bits 64
section .text
global gcdasm
gcdasm:
    movsx rax, edi          ;load rax with x
    movsx rcx, esi          ;load rcx with y
top:
    cmp rax, rcx            ;x(rax) has to be larger than y(rcx)
    je exit                 ;if x=y then exit and return value y
    jb xchange              ;if x<y then swap x and y
modulo:
    cqo                     ;sign extend RDX:RAX
    idiv rcx                ;rdx:rax/rcx (signed values)
    test rdx, rdx           ;check whether remainder is zero
    je exit                 ;if reminder is 0 then exit return y
    mov rax, rcx            ;divisor becomes dividend
    mov rcx, rdx            ;remainder becomes divisor
    jmp modulo              ;loop 
xchange:
    xchg rax, rcx           ;swap x and y
    jmp modulo

exit:
    mov rax, rcx            ;Return c program with the divisor y
    ret
```

Comment: The function signature takes `int` args; the caller is allowed to leave garbage in the high 32 bits of `rdi` and `rsi`, so it's incorrect as well as much slower to use 64-bit `div`.  It's also incorrect to use `div` instead of `idiv` after `cqo`.  (Related: see [GCD in 9 bytes of x86-64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77270/greatest-common-divisor/77364#77364), or 10 bytes for unsigned.  13 bytes for 64-bit operand-size.  Optimized for code-size at the expense of performance, but with much simpler logic than this, and comments / explanation of why it works...)

Comment: @PeterCordes Many thanks for the review. It seems that it's working now for negative numbers as well.

Comment: `movsxd` is one way to solve the problem, but *much* better would be to either change the prototype to `int64_t` or change all register names to `e*x` instead of `r*x`.  Using 64-bit `idiv` on 32-bit operands is the worst of both worlds: larger code-size and [3x worse performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466) for no benefit in terms of range of inputs accepted.

Comment: Also, then you could use `esi` instead of `ecx` everywhere; you still need to copy `edi` to `eax` because `idiv` uses implicit inputs, but choosing `ecx` instead of `ebx` was a missed opportunity to drop the `mov` altogether.

Comment: And BTW, you can use `imul` on signed values if you only want the low half of the result.  e.g. `imul rcx, rdi, 12345` is the same binary operation regardless of whether you interpret it as signed or unsigned.  You're thinking of the one-operand form which matches div/idiv, but your statement that you can't use `idiv` on signed inputs isn't quite true.  In fact you *usually* don't need a full 64x64 -> 128b multiply, so 2 or 3 operand `imul` is the right choice because it's faster (1 uop) and all the operands are explicit (so it doesn't constrain register choice).