# Issue with strchr() function implementation

Tags: unix, assembly, x86-64

I've recently started looking into assembly code and I'm trying to recode some basic system functions to get a grip on it, I'm currently stuck on a segmentation fault at 0x0 on my `strchr`.

```
section .text
global strchr

strchr:
    xor rax, rax

loop:
    cmp BYTE [rdi + rax], 0
    jz end

    cmp sil, 0
    jz end

    cmp BYTE [rdi + rax], sil
    jz good

    inc rax
    jmp loop

good:
    mov rax, [rdi + rcx]
    ret

end:
    mov rax, 0
    ret
```

I can't figure out how to debug it using GDB, also the documentation I've came across is pretty limited or hard to understand.

I'm using the following main in C to test

```
extern char *strchr(const char *s, int c);

int main () {
   const char str[] = "random.string";
   const char ch = '.';
   char *ret;

   ret = strchr(str, ch);
   printf("%s\n", ret);
   printf("String after |%c| is - |%s|\n", ch, ret);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: It seems as though you've got the character to look for in `sil` and you are using `rax` as the offset counter... but when you find the character in the string, `rcx` comes out of nowhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The Problem

The instruction immediately following the `good` label:

```
mov rax, [rdi + rcx]
```

should actually be:

```
lea rax, [rdi + rax]
```

You weren't using `rcx` at all, but `rax` and,  what you need is the *address* of that position, not the value at that position (i.e. `lea` instead of `mov`).

---

#### Some Advice

1. Note that the typical [idiom for comparing `sil` against zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/8012646) is actually `test sil, sil` instead of `cmp sil, 0`. It would be then:

   ```
   test sil, sil
   jz end
   ```

   However, if we look at the [`strchr(3)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html), we can find the following:

   > `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);`
   >
   > The terminating
   >      null byte is considered part of the string, so that if `c` is specified as '`\0'`, these functions return a pointer to the terminator.

   So, if we want this `strchr()` implementation to behave as described in the man page, the following code must be removed:

   ```
   cmp sil, 0
   jz end
   ```
2. The typical [zeroing idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/8012646) for the `rax` register is neither `mov rax, 0` nor `xor rax, rax`, but rather `xor eax, eax`, since it doesn't have the encode the immediate zero and saves one byte respect to the latter.

---

With the correction and the advice above, the code would look like the following:

```
section .text
global strchr

strchr:
    xor eax, eax

loop:
    ; Is end of string?
    cmp BYTE [rdi + rax], 0
    jz end

    ; Is matched? 
    cmp BYTE [rdi + rax], sil
    jz good

    inc rax
    jmp loop

good:
    lea rax, [rdi + rax]
    ret

end:
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: @考えネロク Thanks a lot for the explanation! I've tried correcting it and it still gets a core dumped at 0x1 somehow. // Access not within mapped region.

Comment: @C.Edelweiss Which arguments are you passing to `strchr` ? Are you checking the return value of the function before using it (i.e.: it can be `NULL`) ?

Comment: @考えネロク I'm passing it a const char str[] = "random.string" with a const char c = '.' . The test main crashes before I can check any return. // I've edited the main post with my main.c that i'm using for testing

Comment: The code of your last edit works for me, both for your assembly with just the `lea rax, [rdi + rax]` correction and for my assembly above. The problem seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: my output is `.string
String after |.| is - |.string|
`

Comment: @考えネロク I'll look around for the issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think `test sil, sil` / `jz end` should be removed entirely, not just hoisted out of the loop.  `strchr(string, 0)` should work like strlen, rather than returning not-found.  [The `strchr(3)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) even mentions this case: `if c is specified as '\0', these functions return a pointer to the terminator.`

Comment: Also, it would obviously be better to load the character into a register (with `movzx eax, byte [rdi]`) before testing it twice, because not all x86 CPUs have a load throughput of 2 loads per clock.  (Of course, with the @C.Edelweiss [loop structure, with an extra `jmp` at the bottom instead of a `jnz`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-like-this), it bottlenecks at one iteration per 1.5 clocks even on Haswell.)  I'd just increment `rdi` and load from `[rdi]`.  You want to return a pointer, not a count, so you just need `mov rax, rdi` at the end.

Comment: @PeterCordes How right you are! The implementation was wrong (as clearly stated in the man page). Thank you!!!