# What does "mov ah, 0Bh" / "int 21h" do in DOS assembly?

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16, emu8086

I saw this code to generate and display a square wave on a CRO.

```
data segment

base_add equ 0ef40h
porta equ base_add+0 
portb equ base_add+1
portc equ base_add+2
control_word equ base_add+3

data ends

code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
start : mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov dx, control_word
mov al, 80h
out dx, al


up2:
 mov cx, 000ffh
 mov al, 00h
 mov dx, portb

 mov al, 00h

  here1: out dx,
loop here1

mov cx, 00ffh

     mov al, 0ffh
here2: out dx, al
 loop here2

mov ah, 0bh   ; LINE1
int 21h

or al, al    ; LINE2
jz up2

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Towards the end, what is the use of `mov ah, 0Bh` interrupt and `or al, al`?
Isn't `or al, al` basically just `al`? What is the need to explicitly mention it?
I even tried to find out what 0Bh interrupt does, but I could not make sense out of what I read. Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Use a DOS reference to see what each service does. `0bh` is "Check Standard Input Status". It returns `0` if there is no input available. Yes, the result of `or al,al` is just `al` but more importantly it sets the zero flag if `al` is zero and that's what it is used for in the code. It just waits for a keypress.

Comment: `or al,al` is there to set flags like a comparison of `al` against zero, [as an inefficient alternative to `test al,al`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806) (but had no perf downside on very old CPUs, like before Pentium II, when 16-bit code was common).

Answer (score 2):

That's MSDOS assembly code.

```
mov ah, 0Bh   ; LINE1
int 21h
```

Calls DOS to check whether a character is available on standard input. This call will return 0 if no char available, 0xFF when a character is available. The return value will be given back via the `al` register, so

```
or al, al    ; LINE2
jz up2
```

will test whether a character is available (`or al, al` will only be zero when `al` is zero to begin with), and jump to *up2* if there's nothing to read.

Tip: if you're working with DOS, go grab a copy of Ralf Brown's Interrupt list

- [the original version](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html)
- [a hyperlinked online version](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm)