# Smallest code-size loop to count bits in a register (decrementing another register)?

Tags: assembly, x86, micro-optimization, code-size

I need to write the following C code snippet in 8086*
assembly as short as possible (less than 10
bytes) but I can only manage to write it in 12 bytes.

any ideas?

```
while (ax) {
    bx--;
    ax &= ax-1;
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not necessarily a marketplace. Maybe if you have shared your attempts here, community would be more quick in helping where you need assistance. :)

Comment: @johan : out of fairness I'd point out that this user can't query deleted questions, and the original question actually showed an attempt at a solution. Have to admit I voted to reopen the original. My only real objection to the original was that it probably fell towards the codegolf side of things.

Comment: OK fine, I'll attempt an answer.

Comment: Retitled with a description of what the loop does, so future readers will know what it's about from just the title.

Answer (score 2):

The operation that you're attempting is called a population count, i.e. count the number of set bits in a register.

There is actually a single instruction for that in newer CPU's. And since targeting the orginal 8086 is really not that interesting in 2018.

The simple answer is:

```
f3 0f b8 c0             popcnt eax,eax
29 c3                   sub    ebx,eax
```

6 bytes, which can be reduced to 4 if you're willing to allow a positive value in `ebx` and can assume/assure that ebx is zero to begin with.

Note that there is no need to work with the 16-bit registers, there has not been for many years.

If you want the code to work on the original 8086 (which does not support `popcnt`) you'll have to retain the loop.

The following perfectly straightforward code takes 12 bytes:

```
85 c0                   test   ax,ax          ;is AX zero?
74 08                   je     <done>         ;yes, bail out
<loop>:
4b                      dec    bx             ;bx--
89 c1                   mov    cx,ax
49                      dec    cx             ;cx = ax - 1
21 c8                   and    ax,cx          ;ax = ax & (ax-1) 
75 f8                   jne    <loop>         ;repeat until done
<done>:
```

You can cut this down to 9 bytes by counting the bits in a slightly less efficient way. Here we simply test all 16 bits of ax.

```
<loop>:
d1 e0                   shl    ax,1       ;MSb to carry flag (CF)
83 db 00                sbb    bx,0       ;bx=bx-CF
85 c0                   test   ax,ax      ;is AX zero?
75 f9                   jnz    <loop>     ;if not then loop until done
```

The trick is to understand what the code does and then rephrase it in a different way.

Comment: Please don't recommend obsolete and sub-optimal idioms like `or ax,ax` instead `test ax,ax` for setting flags according to a value in a register.  They're the same length, but [`test` is better in every possible way (except sometimes to avoid register-read stalls on nearly-obsolete Nehalem and earlier)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806).  Neat trick with `pushf`/`popf`; but wouldn't `test ax,ax` achieve *exactly* the same thing here, setting ZF according to the value `shl` left in `ax`?

Comment: @PeterCordes, I seem to recall test reg,reg was introduced in the 386 and thus does not work on the original 8086. Having done some googling it seems I was mistaken. `test` has been with us from the beginning.

Comment: Yup, it existed in 8086, but not 8080, [where `ora, a` was a common idiom, apparently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#comment86128868_33724806)

Comment: The 8086 can't address using `[ax-1]`. The dump `8d 48 ff` corresponds to `lea cx, [bx+si-1]`.