# ASM: operand type mismatch for `cmp'

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm doing x86 asembly code and I keep getting this Error: operand type mismatch for `cmp's

The line of code it appears at is:

```
cmpb %rdi, $0
```

Comment: Since this appears to be AT&T syntax code, the immediate operand should be on the left.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: The immediate might be a byte though. There's both `CMP r/m64, imm8` and `CMP r/m64, imm32`, so you need a way to disambiguate between the two.

Comment: @Michael The size suffix does not indicate the size of the immediate but rather the size of the operation.

Comment: and it's not the best way to check for zero [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33721204/995714)

Answer (score 7):

In AT&T syntax (which is what you use), instructions have a *size suffix* to indicate the operand size.  The size suffixes are:

```
b byte        1 bytes
w word        2 bytes
l long        4 bytes
q quad-word   8 bytes

s single      4 bytes
d double      8 bytes
t temporary  10 bytes
```

For example, `cmpb` is the instruction `cmp` with a 1 byte operand size indicated.  However, your code uses `%rdi` as an operand which is a quad-word (64 bit) register, so the assembler rightfully complains that this is the wrong operand.

To fix this issue, simply leave out the size suffix; the assembler is able to infer it unless all operands are immediates or memory operands:

```
cmp %rdi, $0
```

You can of course also explicitly supply a size suffix; in this case, `q` is appropriate as indicated in the previous table:

```
cmpq %rdi, $0
```

That said, note that as with most instructions, the immediate operand has to be the first operand to `cmpq`:

```
cmpq $0, %rdi
```

The other form is actually illegal.

Comment: `t` usually mean Ten Bytes , not temporary.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That's a kind of retcon; `fstpt` is explicitly called “floating point store temporary” in the 8087 datasheet.

Comment: When it comes to the assemblers  themselves an m80fp is usually identified as TWORD/TBYTE (depends on if you come from a MASM world or not) and the assemblers do not identify a TBYTE/TWORD as a "temporary". The T was to denote a Ten Byte (80-bit) operand.The `t` suffix in AT&T syntax operating in the same capacity.

Comment: `cmp %rdi, $0` is still illegal: x86 only allows an immediate right hand side (Intel syntax) for `cmp` http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html, so only `cmp $0, %rdi` is allowed in AT&T.  If you want to compare in the opposite direction, you need the constant in a register.  (Doesn't matter for `0`, which should use `test %rdi,%rdi` anyway; neither direction can carry or overflow so you can always just use the opposite condition like jge instead of jl)

Comment: @PeterCordes addressed.