# accumulator register 8086 microprocessor family

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, accumulator

Accumulator register is a register that holds temporary values. Only EAX, AX, AL registers are accumulators.

As I know BX, CX, DX and extended versions can hold permanent values. So, why do we  use EAX, AX, AL registers as accumulators?

What is an accumulator?

Comment: What do you mean by “permanent value?”

Comment: the results of arithmetic and logic operations that are not saved anywhere in memory

Comment: But how are these values permanent?

Comment: @fuz I am sorry, not permanent :D temporary

Comment: `ax` is called the accumulator register but it's really no different from the other general purpose registers `bx`, `cx`, `dx`, `si`, `di`, and `bp`.  You can use any of them to hold any value you like.

Comment: ok :) and what actually accumulator is? Is that definition right for accumulator ? I am wondering why do we call AX as an accumulator? Is there any special case for AX?

Comment: Old processors often had just one register used for operating on data.  This register was traditionally called the *accumulator* because old calculators used it to sum up numbers you typed in.  You can think of the 8086 CPU having 7 accumulators (`ax`, `bx`, `cx`, `dx`, `si`, `di`, and `bp`).  Because the 8086 is based on the 8080 which has only one accumulator, the `ax` register is called *accumulator register* because that's what is was on the 8080.

Comment: @fuz I understood)) thank you so much for help

Comment: @fuz - 8080 has a DAD (double add) instruction, where HL is effectively the accumulator.

Comment: BTW, *"eax, ax, al registers"* = it's the same one register, not three registers. Those different aliases just indicate the bit-size the instruction will target/affect (not 100% true/precise in 64b mode, where 32b `eax` target will automatically clear upper 32b, i.e. the instruction like `mov eax,2` will affect whole `rax`). So code: `mov eax,0x11223344` `mov ax,0x5566` `mov al,0xBB` will produce `eax = 0x112255BB` (composed by three different instructions).

Answer (score 6):

On older ancestors of 8086, many instructions were only available with the accumulator as an implicit destination.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing).

The name "accumulator" for 8086's AL/AX register is mostly historical, and related to 8086's design to make asm source translation from 8080 code possible mechanically.  ([Why are first four x86 GPRs named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order) and also [The start of x86: Intel 8080 vs Intel 8086?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/the-start-of-x86-intel-8080-vs-intel-8086))

There are [special short-form encodings of many instructions using AL/AX/EAX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/160739#160739) (like `add al, 2` is 2 bytes, but `add cl, 2` is 3 bytes).  8086 (and later extensions in 186/386) made the registers more orthogonal than 8080 so you can `add dx, cx` without having to use the accumulator for all ALU instructions.

**8086 has a [(mostly) 2-operand instruction set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325275/what-kind-of-address-instruction-does-the-x86-cpu-have), not an [Accumulator Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing)#Accumulator_machines), in terms of instruction format.**  You can save code-size by using the accumulator register, but it's not required for most things especially with later extensions to the x86 ISA.  Compare the x87 FPU instructions: everything has to use `st0` as one of the operands.  (In theoretical CS a [Register Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine) refers to the main memory as "registers", as opposed to a Turing machine with a tape.  Real CPUs have registers *separate* from memory, unlike that idealized model.  x86 instructions can have at most 1 explicit memory operand; the other(s) have to be registers.  https://www.realworldtech.com/architecture-basics/2/ shows a taxonomy of real-world accumulator vs. register designs, with CISC x86 being load-store plus the ability for one or the other operand to be memory.)

---

On many older CPUs, you might have had to do the equivalent of `mov ax,dx` / `add ax, cx`.  For example, 8080 / Z80 had instructions like `LDA` (load into accumulator) and `ORA` (OR into accumulator) where the accumulator destination was baked into the mnemonic and opcode.  (This is where [the inefficient and obsolete `or ax,ax` instead of `test ax,ax` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#comment86128868_33724806) comes from.)

This 8080 opcode map http://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html show many instructions like `SUB D` and `SUB C`, where the implicit first operand is the accumulator, A.

But 8086 is a register machine, not an accumulator machine.  There are several instructions that require using AX, such as `mul` / `div`, and `cdq`, but other than DIV and widening-multiply you can use whatever registers you want with `movsx` on 386 and later, and `imul edx, edi`.

Note that many 8-bit micros that only have ALU instructions using the accumulator aren't always pure accumulator machines as far as theory-of-computation.  They typically have other registers they can use for addressing modes.  But they are typically [1-operand instruction sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture#Number_of_operands).

Answer (score 4):

AX isn't any more or less temporary than the other registers.

Link to wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing)

```
8080 to 8086 register mapping and legacy name

A       AL   accumulator
H,L     BX   high, low memory pointer
B,C     CX   byte counter (also a memory pointer)
D,E     DX   data         (also a memory pointer)
SP      SP   stack pointer
...     SI   source index
...     DI   destination index
...     BP   base pointer (uses SS as default segment)
```