# What kind of address instruction does the x86 cpu have?

Tags: x86, cpu, computer-science, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I learned about one address, two address, and three address instruction, but now I'd like to know, what kind of address instruction does x86 use?

Comment: By "address", do you mean "operand"?

Comment: @Sneftel: yes, in abstract ISA-classification terminology, it means operand.  like the 5-bit register fields in a MIPS instruction word are "addresses".  (I don't know if https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/computer-organization-instruction-formats-zero-one-two-three-address-instruction/ is any good, but that's the terminology they use)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

x86 is a CISC [register machine](https://www.realworldtech.com/architecture-basics/2/), where at most 1 operand for any instruction can be an *explicit* memory address instead of a register, using an addressing mode like `[rdi + rax*4]`.  (There are instruction which can have 2 memory operands with one or both being implicit, though: [What x86 instructions take two (or more) memory operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573554/what-x86-instructions-take-two-or-more-memory-operands))

**Typical x86 integer instructions have 2 operands, both explicit, like [`add eax, edx`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html)** which does `eax+=edx`.

And some truly 1-operand ALU instructions (no implicit other operand) like `inc`/`dec`, `neg`, `not` which are shortcuts for add/sub of implicit 1, or sub from 0, or XOR with -1 (some with different FLAGS semantics).  And there's `bswap`.  Also the shift/rotate instructions with an implicit 1 count are basically 1-operand, and some assemblers do let you write `shr %eax`.

**Legacy x87 FP code uses 1-operand instructions with the x87 stack, like `faddp st1`** where the top of the x87 stack (`st0`) is an implicit operand.  And some 0-operand instructions like `fchs` that operate only on `st0` implicitly.  (SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, so x87 is no longer widely used.)

**Modern FP code uses SSE/SSE2 2-operand instructions like `addsd xmm0,xmm1` or 3-operand AVX encodings like `vaddsd xmm2, xmm0, xmm1`**

**There are x86 instructions with 0, 1, 2, 3, and even 4 *explicit* operands.**

There are multiple instruction formats, but explicit reg/memory operands are normally encoded in a ModR/M byte that follows the opcode byte(s). ([x86-64 instruction encoding on osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#ModR.2FM_and_SIB_bytes) has good details and diagrams). It has 3 fields:

- 2-bit Mode for the r/m operand (register direct `reg`, register indirect `[reg]`, `[reg+disp8]`, `[reg+disp32]`).  The modes with displacement bits signal that those bytes follow the ModR/M byte.
- 3-bit r/m field (the register number for register direct or indirect, or can be an escape code that means there's a Scale/Index/Base SIB byte after ModRM which can encode scaled-index addressing modes for the r/m operand).  See [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base) for the details of the special cases / escape codes.
- 3-bit reg field, always a register number.  (Or in one-operand or `r/m, immediate` instructions, [used as extra opcode bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017659/how-to-read-the-intel-opcode-notation/53976236#53976236), e.g. for shifts/rotates selects which kind.)

Most instructions are available in at least 2 encodings, reg/memory destination or reg/memory source.  If the operands you want are both registers, you can use either opcode, either the `add r/m32, r32` or `add r32, r/m32`.  (Some assemblers [have syntax to let you select the non-default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336269/x86-xor-opcode-differences).  In theory an assembler / compiler could use these choices as a watermark to show which tool produced it.)

Common instructions also have other opcodes for immediate source forms, but typically they use the `reg` field in ModR/M as extra opcode bits, so you still only get 2 operands like `add eax, 123`.  An exception to this is the immediate form of `imul` added with 186, e.g. [`imul eax, [rdi + rbx*4], 12345`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html).  Instead of sharing coding space with other immediate instructions, it has a register dst and a r/m source in ModR/M *plus* the immediate operand implied by the opcode.

Some one-operand instructions use the same trick of using the `reg` field as extra opcode bits, but without an immediate.  e.g. `neg r/m32`, `not r/m32`, `inc r/m32`, or the `shl`/`shr`/rotate encodings that shift by an implicit 1 (not by `cl` or an immediate).  So unfortunately you can't copy-and-shift (until BMI2).

There are some special-case encodings to improve code density, like single-byte encodings for `push rax`/`push rdx` that pack the `reg` field into the low 3 bits of the opcode byte.  And in 16/32-bit mode, one-byte encodings for `inc`/`dec` any register.  But in 64-bit mode those `0x4?` codes are used as REX prefixes to extend the `reg` and `r/m` fields to provide 16 architectural registers.

---

**There are also instructions with some or all implicit operands**, like `movsb` which copies a byte from `[rsi]` to `[rdi]`, and can be used with a `rep` prefix to repeat that `rcx` times.

Or `mul ecx` does `edx:eax = eax * ecx`.  One explicit source operand, one implicit source, and 2 implicit destination registers.  `div`/`idiv` are similar.

Instructions with at least 1 explicit reg/mem operand use a ModR/M encoding for it, but instructions with zero explicit operands (like `movsb` or [`cdq`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CWD:CDQ:CQO.html)) have no ModR/M byte.  They just have the opcode.  Some instructions have no operands at all, not even implicit, [like `mfence`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MFENCE.html).

Immediate operands can't be signalled through ModR/M, only by the opcode itself, so [`push imm32` or `push imm8`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html) have their own opcodes.  The implicit destinations (memory at `[rsp]`, and RSP itself being updated to `rsp-=8`).

---

**LEA is a workaround that gives x86 3-operand shift-and-add**, like `lea eax, [rdi + rdi*2 + 123]` to do `eax = rdi*3 + 123` in one instruction.  See [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers)  The destination register is encoded in ModR/M's `reg` field, and the two source registers are encoded in the addressing mode.  (Involving a SIB byte, the presence of which is signalled by the ModR/M byte using the encoding that would otherwise mean base = RSP).

---

**VEX prefixes (introduced with AVX) provide 3-operand instructions like [`bzhi eax, [rsi], edx`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BZHI.html) or `vaddps ymm0, ymm1, [rsi]`.**  (For many instructions, the 2nd source is the one that's optionally memory, but for some it's the first source.)

The 3rd operand is encoded in the 2 or 3-byte VEX prefix.

---

There are a few 3-operand non-VEX instructions, such as SSE4.1 variable blends like [`vpblendvb xmm1, xmm2/m128, <XMM0>`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PBLENDVB.html) where XMM0 is an implicit operand using that register.

The AVX version makes it non-destructive (with a separate destination encoded in the VEX prefix), *and* makes the blend-control operand explicit (encoded in the high 4 bits of a 1-byte immediate).  **This gives us an instruction with 4 explicit operands, `VPBLENDVB xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m128, xmm4`.**

---

x86 is pretty wild and has been extended many times, but typical integer code uses mostly 2-operand instructions, with a good amount of LEA thrown in to save instructions.

Comment: The [two and three operand `IMUL`](https://ulukai.org/ecm/insref.htm#insIMUL) was actually introduced with the 186, not 286 as you wrote. Also, you first list that the reg field of the ModR/M byte is "3-bit reg field, always a register number", then eventually you add that it can extend the opcode depending. I'd mention this in the list entry already.

Comment: @ecm: Good suggestion about /r, thanks.  And yeah, I told you last time this came up that I probably had several answers that included the old NASM appendix's wrong info about when imul was new.  I'll see if I can search up other cases.

Comment: @ecm: Wasn't 2-operand `0F AF  imul r, r/m` new in 386, not 186?  Your https://ulukai.org/ecm/insref.htm and current https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html both say that.  http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/intel/80186/210911-001_iAPX86_88_186_188_Programmers_Reference_1983.pdf only mentions immediate imul, not the 2-operand form (strangely as a single-operand immediate, unlike another 186 manual).  When you said 2-operand, were you counting the `imul eax, 123` form where assemblers let you omit mentioning the first source if it's the same as the destination?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the short form of the three-operand instruction with the destination and one source the same register, and the last operand being an immediate. However, I should have been clearer in that; I did actually miss the two-operand form without an immediate operand. You're right that that one is a 386+ instruction.

Comment: @ecm:  Ok, good. As you know, in machine code imul-immediate always has 3 operands, it's just a source-level shorthand.  Since there is a 2-operand form which is a different instruction, IMO it's best to just talk about the number of real machine-code operands, regardless of how you write it in the source, at least when talking about which forms exist and were introduced when.  Because that's a machine-code issue.  And BTW, I finally got around to searching and editing my answers that mention "imul" and "286".  About a dozen of them so far.

Comment: Update: APX will provide EVEX 3-operand encodings of classic integer instructions like `sub`.  (And 2-operand version of `not` / `neg`).  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html