# How to read this line with three(?) operands?

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to understand the basics but so far I can only see examples with two operands:

`ADD <target> <source>` means, the values in the <> brackets are summed and stored in < target > . I get this.
But how do I read this:

`ADD R10 0x8 R5` ?

`R5` and `R10` mean the addresses in registers, right? What is 0x8?

I would try to transfer as following:

`R10 + 0x8 + R5` and store it in `R10`. Whatever `R5`, `R10` and `0x8` is.

Comment: What architecture is this?  Please tag your question accordingly.  Where did you see the line your're quoting, and in what context?  Can you give a link to the original source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost always, 3-operand ISAs are `op dst, src1, src2`, where dst is write-only instead of also being a source.

e.g. AArch64 `add x1, x2, x3` does `x1 = x2 + x3`, not destroying either of the original input operands.

But for any given ISA, read the manual and it will tell you exactly what each instruction does.  I don't recognize the syntax you're using: it's unusual to have a numeric literal constant as the *middle* operand.  I've only ever seen syntaxes that put the immediate as the last source.  (Or for `op src, src, dst`, as the first source).  e.g. MIPS `addiu $v0, $a0, 123`.  Omitting commas between operands is a weird thing that some MIPS simulators allow, and maybe standard syntax for some other ISAs including whatever this is.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the center line but that is enough for me :)
Are four operands also possible? Just curious.

Comment: @Ben: Sure, x86's AVX extension introduces a 4-operand form of [`vpblendvb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pblendvb).  And arguably, AVX-512 zero-masked and merge-masked instructions are 4 operands, including the mask register even though the syntax is like `vaddps zmm0{k1}, zmm1, zmm2`.  There are 4 register-number fields in the overall instruction encoding.  See [What kind of address instruction does the x86 cpu have?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53325275).

Comment: Or if you count separate immediate fields as separate operands, PowerPC `rlwinm` has 2 register-numbers and 3 separate immediates for a total of 5 comma-separated operands in the asm source-level syntax.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/assembler/idalangref_rlwinm_rlinm_rtlwrdimm_instrs.html

Comment: I guess you're much too advanced for my simple brain but it's interesting to watch/read :) I'll try to understand by reading up a "bit".