# What are intrinsics sequence functions?

Tags: intel, intrinsics, avx

On the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide) there are some [functions](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#!=undefined&text=reduce&expand=4618,4557) that are not mapped to assembly instructions and so are marked with `...` on the right and have no Performance (latency and throughput) information. These are marked as `Sequence` instructions so my guess is that these are actual functions provided by `immintrin.h` that can be used instead of manual implementations for those tasks.
But what I don't understand is, are these just useful functions that Intel couldn't/wouldn't implement as real instructions or are they wrappers to possible future versions of the avx/avx2/avx512 extensions ?
I couldn't find any official information nor other sources on this topic (my main sources are the Intel Intrinsics Guide as well as the [Intel Compiler User Guide](https://ww2.lacan.upc.edu/doc/intel/compiler_c/main_cls/index.htm) (although I work with gcc))

Answer (score 2):

Things like `_mm_set_epi32(int, int, int, int)` would make no sense as a single machine instruction.  It would need four `r/m32` or register-only source operands (and an XMM destination), but x86 machine-code only ever has at most 3 operands *including* the destination.  (Although for FMA all 3 are inputs).  The only exception is `vblendvps/pd` and `vpblendvb` where an immediate byte encodes a 4th operand, but that's still only 4 total, and not 4 reg/mem and a separate destination.

See also [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794169/why-isnt-movl-from-memory-to-memory-allowed) and [What kind of address instruction does the x86 cpu have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325275/what-kind-of-address-instruction-does-the-x86-cpu-have)

---

And often you `_mm_set` with constants, and want the compiler to do constant-propagation to make a single vector constant.  If you wanted a gather-load of pointers, you'd use [`_mm_i32gather_epi32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherdd:vpgatherqd) with a vector of indices.

So generally no, they're not placeholders for planned future instructions, they're basically just convenience functions whose implementation can vary a lot depending on whether the input operands are in memory or registers.  (e.g. vector shuffles).  And depending on what feature-level is available, e.g. SSE4.1 `pinsrd` can be useful as part of `_mm_set_epi32(0,0,b,a)`.

Or prototypes for SVML math functions like `_mm_sin_ps`, not really intrinsics at all.  Intel uses the same `_mm` naming scheme and includes those in a section of the intrinsics guide partly as a convenience for people using Intel's own compiler (which comes with SVML), and perhaps partly to trick / trap people into depending on Intel APIs that make it harder to port their code to other compilers that have intrinsics but not SVML.

Or they're casts like `_mm256_castsi256_si128` which is free in asm, just use the XMM low half of the register.

The C intrinsics API doesn't even have a way to ask for a `__m128` where the low element is a scalar `float`, and the upper elements are don't-care, you only have `_mm_set1_ps` broadcast or `_mm_set_ss` zero-extend, and not all compilers can optimize that away if you only use the `__m128` with things that don't care about the upper elements.  (Clang's shuffle optimizer can see what's going on.)  That's annoying because a scalar float in a register *is* just the low element of an XMM, but there's no equivalent to `_mm256_castps128_ps256` (which gives you a vector with a don't-care upper half).

---

**It would be plausible for some future CPU to introduce an instruction like `vsinps`** to do in hardware what the SVML library function does, but unlikely.  `sin` is too much work for one pipelined execution unit of reasonable length.  x87 `fsin` is microcoded as 53-105 uops on Skylake for example (https://agner.org/optimize/  / https://uops.info/), and it's not generally faster than a well-optimized software implementation.  Full hardware/microcode `fsin` is convenient for toy programs written in asm, but it's not a big deal either way for real-world code that leaves that up to a compiler / math library.

Also, doing `sin` in hardware / microcode nails down speed vs. precision tradeoffs in ways that might not be what people want.  Also related: [Intel Underestimates Error Bounds by 1.3 quintillion](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/) - fsin is quite inaccurate for inputs very near Pi, and Intel only recently fixed their documentation.  (It's not like software has an easier time, although you can use extended-precision to gain accuracy.)  Presumably, a SIMD float version of the same instruction would have the same accuracy problems.