# sha256rnds2 implicit register xmm0

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu, cpu-architecture, sha256

According to [[1]](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sha256rnds2) `sha256rnds2` instruction has an implicit 3rd operand that uses register `xmm0`. This is the thing that prevents me from having an effective computation of `sha256` over multiple buffers simultaneously and thus hopefully fully utilizing CPU's execution pipelines and conveyor.

Other multibuffer implementations (e.g. [[2]](https://github.com/intel/intel-ipsec-mb/blob/main/lib/sse/sha256_ni_x2_sse.asm), [[3]](https://github.com/intel/isa-l_crypto/blob/master/sha256_mb/sha256_ni_x2.asm)) use two different techniques to overcome this:

1. Compute rounds sequentially
2. Partially utilize parallelization when it's possible

The question I have - why this instruction was designed in this way - to have an implicit barrier that prevents us from utilizing multiple execution pipelines or to effectively use two sequential instructions due to reciprocal throughput.

I see three possible reasons:

1. Initially SHA-NI was considered as an extension for low-performance CPUs. And no one thought that it will be popular in high-perf CPUs - hence no support of multiple pipelines.
2. There is a limit from instruction encoding/decoding side - there are no enough bits to encode 3rd register that is why it's hardcoded.
3. `shar256rnds2` has tremendous energy consumption and this is why it's not possible to have multiple execution pipelines for it.

Links:

1. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sha256rnds2
2. https://github.com/intel/intel-ipsec-mb/blob/main/lib/sse/sha256_ni_x2_sse.asm
3. https://github.com/intel/isa-l_crypto/blob/master/sha256_mb/sha256_ni_x2.asm

Comment: With register renaming, the fixed implicit operand shouldn't really interfere with simultaneous execution.  In other words, if you write `sha256rnd xmm1, xmm2 ; movdqa xmm0, xmm3 ; sha256rnd xmm4, xmm5` then nothing prevents the two `sha256rnd`s from executing simultaneously in separate pipelines, as they have no dependencies.  The architectural `xmm0` would be renamed to different internal registers for the different instructions.

Comment: So the underlying reason is probably #2, but its impact is not as much as you think.  Of course, due to #1 and #3, any given CPU may or may not actually have more than one pipeline that can execute this instruction - but if it does, there's no reason you can't use them all.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Looks like they wanted to avoid a VEX encoding, so they could provide SHA extensions on low-power Silvermont-family CPUs that don't have AVX/BMI instructions.  (Where it's most useful.)  So (1) led to (2), but not because of it's not pipelined.  According to https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/, Ice Lake has one execution unit for `SHA256RNDS2` on port 5, with 6 cycle latency but pipelined at 3c throughput.  So 2 can be in flight at once.  Not close to a front-end bottleneck with an extra `movdqa`.

Comment: It's equally pipelined in Goldmont, with SHA256RNDS2 as 3 uops, 8c latency, 4c throughput.  While SHA1 is better pipelined (1 uop, 5c lat, 2c tput).  Zen2 also has one pipelined execution unit; Zen3 has two units, 4c latency 2c throughput for SHA256.

Comment: Swapping xmm0 beside `movdqa` requires stores/loads from memory - 7 xmm registers are used per buffer: two for states and five for msgtmps. For two buffers I need 14 registers + 1 xmm0. The last register might be used either for SHUF_MASK or as a scratch for xmm0. In either case there is a register spilling.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Fortunately L1d cache is fast, so you're probably fine reloading XMM0 (or some other read-only vector constant) from stack space (or .rodata if it's a true constant, not just loop-invariant).  You'd want to *avoid* store/reload if you can, as that potentially puts store-forwarding latency on the critical path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Register renaming makes this a non-problem for the back-end**.  (See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) for info on how register renaming hides write-after-write and write-after-read hazards.)

At worst this costs you an extra `movdqa xmm0, whatever` or `vmovdqa` instruction before some or all of your `sha256rnds2` instructions, costing a small amount of front-end throughput.  Or I guess if you're out of registers, then maybe an extra load, or even a store/reload.

Looks like they wanted to avoid a VEX encoding, so they could provide SHA extensions on low-power Silvermont-family CPUs that don't have AVX/BMI instructions. (Where it's most useful because the CPU is slower relative to the amount of data it's throwing around.)  So yes, [only 2 *explicit* operands could be encoded via the normal ModRM mechanism in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325275/what-kind-of-address-instruction-does-the-x86-cpu-have).  x86 does three-register instructions with VEX prefixes, which provide a new field for another 4-bit register number.  (`vblendvb` has 4 explicit operands, with the 4th register number as an immediate, but that's crazy and requires special decoder support.)

**So (1) led to (2), but not because of any lack of pipelining.**

According to https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/, the `SHA256RNDS2` and instruction is at least partially pipelined on all CPUs that support it.  Ice Lake has one execution unit for SHA256RNDS2 on port 5, with 6 cycle latency but pipelined at 3c throughput. So 2 can be in flight at once. Not close to a front-end bottleneck with an extra `movdqa`.

Comment: Do you have more information on the special decoder support for 4-register blend?

Comment: @PaoloBonzini: It's the only instruction that has to get a register number from an immediate, so the logic gates in the decoders that can handle that instruction at all must be able to mux that field to a register-number field in a uop.  Since Intel CPUs handle it as multi-uop, it can only decode in the "complex" (first) decoder (https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/2/)