# Set all bits in byte high if one is high

Tags: c++, c

I need to set all bits in a byte high if any of its bits are high. If none of them is high, all bits should be low.

So if the byte is `0000 1000` it should be set to `1111 1111` and if it is`0000 0000`, it should just stay `0000 0000`.

How would i go about doing that without having to use if statements?

I already tried to do this with bitwise operators, but i couldn't quite figure out how to do this.

I also searched on the internet (also Stackoverflow) on how to do this, but i didn't find anything.

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried, and ask if anyone can see how to improve it?

Comment: `if (byte) byte |= 0xff;` or just `if (byte) byte = 0xff;`

Comment: Something like `result = input & 0xFFFF` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set all bits if `a` is not `0`. A simple way to do this is:

```
unsigned char setallbits(unsigned char a) {
    return (a != 0) ? ~0U : 0;
}
```

To avoid a test, you can consider that `a != 0` will evaluate to `1` or `0`, then negate that:

```
unsigned char setallbits(unsigned char a) {
    return -(a != 0);
}
```

Or use the idioamtic `!!a` to convert `a` to a boolean:

```
unsigned char setallbits(unsigned char a) {
    return -!!a;
}
```

The last 2 functions assume two's complement representation of negative values. The purists can achieve portability to obsolete architectures that represent negative integers with sign/magnitude or ones' complement with `-(unsigned)(a != 0)` or `-(unsigned char)!!a` which are as cryptic as expected.

Comment: Assumes two's complement, but yes, very good solution if that assumption holds (which it almost always does).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I heard we're getting guaranteed two's complement in C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yeah, but I think it'll be another few years before we can assume everyone is compiling targeting C++20.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I added the cast for portability to the DS9K

Comment: What is this? A lesson in code obfuscation? Have you considered entering the IOCCC? https://www.ioccc.org/

Comment: @RichardHodges: do you like this version better? I have never entered the IOCCC myself, but did motivate a famous multiple winner.

Comment: in the fact !! or != means the `if` in the background

Comment: @P__J__: not necessarily. On x86 it usually generates a `cmp` and a `set ah` from flags.

Comment: @chqrlie: I'd assume it usually generates a `test`, not a `cmp`, given `test` [is (slightly) more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806/364696). In local tests, I reliably see all three versions implemented as `test`, `setne`, `neg`, `retq`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple if does the job:

```
if (byte) {
    byte = -1; // 0xFFFF..
}
```

Comment: An optimiser can, and for example [clang does](https://godbolt.org/z/YrQ8ii) produce identical code for this, as for the bit twiddling solutions.

Comment: Yes it will do fine, but I wanted to avoid if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Not signed version:

```
unsigned char foo(unsigned char x)
{
    return x ? ~0 : x;
}
```

All the solutions with !! or != imply the conditional statement.

Comment: unoptimized gcc generates branches for the ternary operator, but not for the `!!` nor the `!=` versions. All three generate the same branchless code with `-O1` or better: https://godbolt.org/z/jSWhqO

Comment: @chqrlie but '-' imlies the two complement - and as I know usually you criticize everyone assuming it for non porability

Comment: `-` applied to a signed int (after promotion) has this problem, not when applied to an `unsigned int` argument. I'm sorry I come across as *criticizing* non portability to non two's complement architectures. I wish two's complement was mandated by the C Standard as it is in POSIX. This portability non-sense is just a byzantine quarrel among experts. It probably puts newbies off and seems futile with good reason. I shall try to be more careful and reserve this to language-lawyer specific questions.