# how to interpret x86-64 xor followed by jle?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, eflags

If part of the assembly code is as following:

```
xor %ebp,%ebx
jle some address
```

does this jle means that it will jump when (%ebx ^ %ebp == 0) because that would set ZF to 1?

Answer (score 5):

That's one of the ways JLE can be true.  The other is `SF≠ OF`, as per the manual:
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc

Since XOR always clears OF, `SF != OF` reduces to just SF.

**`jle` after a boolean op will be taken if `SF | ZF`, i.e. if the result is `<= 0`.**

Interesting optimization to avoid `test %ebx,%ebx` to compare the result against zero ([AND or TEST same,same sets FLAGS identically to `cmp reg,0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806)).

Comment: So it will jump if `%ebp` and `%ebx` differ in their most-significant bits or are equal?  It's hard to imagine when that would be useful except as an exam question.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I thought about saying something in my answer about it not telling you much about the inputs, because yeah it doesn't seem like a meaningful thing to test,  unless maybe one of the registers can only have its sign bit set or not, or something like that.  But it seems plausible you could do something with the result of an XOR that would make a compiler want to test it for `>0`.  Doing something else with the result, treating it as a signed integer, can certainly lead to a compiler optimizing that along with the xor; that kind of thing is exactly why we use compilers.