# Can't figure out how to implement while loop correctly in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to implement the following pseudocode in assembly:
[image]

My solution tries to implement the while loop using a LOOP instruction, but this gives me an infinite loop. (I know this is b/c of the garbage values in the ECX, but I don't understand how to overcom this problem and correctly implement the WHILE loop). Here's my code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
A WORD 9
B WORD 8
X WORD 15
sum WORD 0

.code
main PROC
L1:
    cmp X, 3     
    jne ELSEE   ;jump to ELSEE if X!=3 (short circuits the AND condition)
    mov ax, A+3
    cmp X, ax
    jle TRUE  ;jump to TRUE if X<=A+3
    mov bx, B-3
    cmp X, bx
    jl TRUE ;jump to TRUE if X<B-3
    cmp X,0
    jge WHYLE

    TRUE:
        sub X,2
        inc sum
    ELSEE:
        dec X
WHYLE:
    loop L1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Since you can't easily calculate the number of iterations ahead of time, don't use `loop`.  use `test eax,eax` / `jge` as the loop branch to implement the `while(x>=0)` logic. (With X in EAX)

Comment: Also, `mov bx, B-3` is a word load from the address `[B-3]`, that's also not what your pseudocode is doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes could you please elaborate on your first comment about using the `test` instruction

Comment: Look at compiler output for a C version of the pseudocode; e.g. from https://godbolt.org/ with `gcc -Og -m32` or MSVC. ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).  For test/jge specifically, [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806).  Using cmp/`jcc` for a loop isn't fundamentally different from using it for an `if`, it's just a matter of jumping backwards to re-run the loop body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the comparison yields greater or equal, jump to the start, otherwise continue out of the loop, e.g. to the exit call.  This is effectively a [`do{}while()` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump), which is most natural in asm.  Since you can't easily calculate ahead of time how many iterations the loop needs to run, you can't use the `loop` instruction as the loop condition.

There are other bugs inside you loop body, but this is how to loop.  You might want to keep `X` in a register instead of using memory every time you access it.

```
    cmp X,0
    jl SKIP      ; skip the loop entirely if the condition is false to start with

L1:              ; do {

   ;;; loop body goes here
    
    cmp X,0
    jge L1       ; }while(X >= 0);
SKIP:

   ;; after the loop
```

Comment: Yup, that's the standard way to make a `while()` loop.  There are in fact several other bugs (like the if/else logic, and doing memory offsets instead of load / add), so maybe it would be better to cut out all the other code and just say "loop body goes here" without showing the still-wrong code.