# Checking if the result is 0 without CMP? Assembly x86 MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have the following code:

```
or edx,edx          (0 Or 0 would equal 0)
jz InvalidDivisor
```

If i change the code to this:

```
AND edx,edx            (0 and 0 would equal 0)
jz InvalidDivisor
```

Wouldnt both ways work for checking to see if the product is 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These both work, but `test edx, edx` does the same and is more idiomatic than either one of them.

It may also be more efficient because I would guess that either `or` or `and` would appear to the CPU as though they possibly modify the value of the register, since `or edx, XXX` would do so in general, and the CPU probably doesn't check for this special case.  This could mean that later instructions using the value of `edx` have to stall until the `or/and` finishes executing, whereas with `test` those later instructions can go ahead and execute out-of-order without waiting for `test` to finish.

Comment: Yes, `test` is more efficient in many cases, including allowing fusion with JCC on AMD CPUs, and earlier Intel.  There's a canonical duplicate for this: [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806)