# SIGFP - But no division by 0 or by big number | MASM/UASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, sigfpe, jwasm

Performing a division by 10, I get a "floating point exception".
when stepping through the code in GDB, I find that ax = 23 and bx = 10 when dividing.

```
.686                                    ;
                                        ;
BSS SEGMENT                             ;
    BUF DB 0                            ;
BSS ENDS                                ;
                                        ;
DATA SEGMENT                            ;
    ASSUME DS:BSS                       ;
                                        ;
PUBLIC _start                           ;
_start PROC                             ;
    MOV cx, 230                         ;
    CALL prN                            ;
                                        ;
...
_start ENDP                             ;
                                        ;
;---------------------------------------;
; prNum                                 ;
; TOFIX: numbers are printed backwards  ;
;---------------------------------------;
; CX = number to print                  ;
;---------------------------------------;
prN PROC                                ;
    MOV ax, cx                          ; prepare first loop
    MOV bx, 10                          ; !! BX = 10
@@loop:                                 ;
    ;- PROBLEMATIC LINE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv;
    DIV bx                              ; Get rightmost decimal digit
    ;- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^;
    ADD dl, '0'                         ; convert to ASCII-numeral
    MOV BYTE PTR [BUF], dl              ;
    PUSHA                               ; Not ideal, this is a playground
    ;- print byte buffer                ;
...
    ;--                                 ;
    POPA                                ;
    OR ax, ax                           ; Is cx = 0?
    JNZ @@loop                          ; NO: loop for the next decimal part
    RET                                 ; YES: leave loop
prN ENDP                                ;
DATA ENDS
END
```

Example runthrough of Loop (as I imagine it):

```
MOV ax, cx ; ax = 230
MOV bx, 10 ; bx = 10
           ;
(@@loop)   ;
DIX bx     ; ax = 23 - dx = 0
;- print   ; STDOUT = 0
OR ax, ax  ; ZF = 0
JNZ @@loop ; continue looping with AX = 23

DIV bx     ; AX = 2 - DX = 3 --> THIS is where the SIGFPE occurs
;- print   ; STDOUT = 03
OR ax, ax  ; ZF = 0
JNZ @@loop ; continue looping with AX = 2
           ;
DIX bx     ; AX = 0 - DX = 2
;- print   ; STOUD = 032 (230 but backwards)
OR ax, ax  ; ZF = 1
JNZ @@loop ; not looping
RET        ; all done, we are returning
```

Since I am dividing 23 by 10, I expect this operation to be problem-free.
In particular:

- No division by zero
- No overflow
- No underflow

I expect

```
AX = 2
DX = 3
BX = 10
```

Comment: Just curious, but how are you using [masm] on an OS that has a [sigfpe]? (Linux, MacOS, *BSD, etc.  But not Windows, it doesn't have POSIX signals.)  Are you maybe using JWASM to build MASM syntax into Linux executables?  Or are you using Windows or DOS, but mis-tagged [sigfpe] instead of [floating-point-exception] or something?  I forget if any non-POSIX OSes report integer arithmetic exceptions like `#DE` as floating-point exceptions

Comment: Also curious why you're using 16-bit registers for a Unix-like OS; the mainstream ones all use 32 or 64-bit mode so the normal thing is 32-bit integer registers; using 16-bit registers needs larger machine code (prefixes) and is slower.  And BTW, `or ax,ax` is an obsolete idiom that comes from 8080.  `test ax,ax` does the same thing but is more efficient.  [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806)

Comment: Oh I see UASM in the title, so it is derived from JWASM.  Yeah, the [masm] tag is appropriate I guess, JWASM is essentially just MASM syntax, although there is a [jwasm] tag that we should use.

Comment: This code is almost a straight copy from my bootloader - it acted crazy and I wanted to dissect it in a clean environment.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, yeah assembling 16-bit code for 32-bit mode usually Just Works after changing pointers to 32-bit.  Except stuff like `push 123` defaulting to a dword push instead of word.  Bochs has a built-in debugger that lets you single-step a legacy BIOS MBR bootloader (or presumably a modern EFI bootloader), but playing around with stuff in a user-space process is easier.

Comment: I just checked test - https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_315.html
It does NOT do the same as `or ax, ax`, it performs an `and ax, ax` which is NOT the behaviour I want, I'd need to `test ax, 0FFFFH`, which encodes in 3 bytes instead of 2. Also, I doubt that there is a speed difference, the stackoverflow-page you linked for this is not relevant (CMP vs OR vs TEST)

Comment: They differ if used with different registers, but `ax` = `ax & ax` = `ax | ax`; look at the truth-table for AND and OR when both values are the same if you're not convinced. They both set FLAGS according to the value in AX, the same way `cmp ax,0` does.  Read the linked Q&A again, it explains why there's a speed difference: extra latency in the critical path for later uses of `ax` on modern out-of-order exec CPUs.

Comment: You can also use my bootable 86-DOS debugger, install it into a disk image then load your program from within the debugger and trace or examine it that way. Downloads and manual at https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug

Answer (score 2):

Oversight on my part. The 16-bit `DIV` operation takes in DX:AX.
With DX being 0x0030 in the first pass, the number I was dividing seemed not to be valid anymore:

```
DX = 0x0030 (48 in decimal)
AX = 0x0017 (23 in decimal)
```

0x00300017 divided by 10 is bigger than 0xFFFF.

> ```
> if(Source == 0) Exception(DE); //divide error
>
> if(OperandSize == 8) { //word/byte operation
>   Temporary = AX / Source;
>   if(Temporary > 0xFF) Exception(DE); //divide error
>   else {
>       AL = Temporary;
>       AH = AX % Source;
>   }
> }
> else if(OperandSize == 16) { //doubleword/word operation
>   Temporary = DX:AX / Source;
>   if(Temporary > 0xFFFF) Exception(DE); //divide error
>   else {
>       AX = Temporary;
>       DX = DX:AX % Source;
>   }
> }
> else { //quadword/doubleword operation
>   Temporary = EDX:EAX / Source;
>   if(Temporary > 0xFFFFFFFF) Exception(DE); //divide error
>   else {
>       EAX = Temporary;
>       EDX = EDX:EAX % Source;
>   }
> }
> ```

https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html