# Detect null byte in a (16 bit) word in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, micro-optimization, bitmask

I have to detect a null byte in a word, So I have to check if 8 of the 16 bits are zero, so basically either the front 8 bits or the back. The problem is I can't use a lot of cycles. So I need a bit mask, that checks the front and the back in just one operation. So first checking `bl` and then `bh` doesn't work as it takes to long. The other null byte posts never really address a real 16-bit word. (assembly)

I already tried 0xff and 0x00ff but can't combine them into one bit mask

Comment: Why are you sure it is possible in x86 with a single instruction?

Comment: You can create 65536-byte lookup table and read value indexed by `bx`, but it is very inefficient.

Comment: I already did it for doubleword and quadword with bit masks, but just can't figure out a bitmaskt for word.

Comment: The method with bit masks can probably be "narrowed" to make it suitable for words. Which method did you use?

Comment: @harold With a single instruction? Please show us how.

Comment: @dimich after OP shows me how he did it for a dword/qword

Comment: @harold Sorry, i mentioned you mistakenly. The question is for OP.

Comment: Please specify the *instruction set architecture* explicitly.

Comment: The 4-operation bithack shown in https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord (`#define haszero(v) (((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)`) works just fine for 16-bit or 64-bit inputs, it's just usually not worth it vs. two separate macro-fuse `test/jz` uops.  Comments on [How to check if a register contains a zero byte without SIMD instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134703423) discuss the 64-bit case.

Answer (score 2):

A mask isn't needed, but it takes two instructions:

```
        mul     ah      ;multiply al by ah
        test    ax,ax   ;set zero flag if ax = 0
```

Comment: 8-bit `mul` is fast on a modern x86 (https://uops.info/), but on older CPUs it would be faster to run more instructions (for example on P5 Pentium, `mul ah` takes 11 cycles: https://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~fpf/Uebungen/GdR-SS02/opcode_i.html).  (OP hasn't said what they're optimizing for).

Comment: Use `test ax,ax` instead of `or`, especially if the next instruction is a `jcc`: `test` can macro-fuse, `or` can't, on current CPUs.  [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33721204)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I updated my answer. As noted, OP doesn't specify what CPU.

Comment: Right, I forgot to add that `test ax,ax` isn't worse anywhere (except in odd cases on P6-family where rewriting a register with the same value might reduce register-read stalls if the value is read again later after this.).  That's what makes it a bad idea to ever use `or` in cases like this where we don't know which CPUs they care about.